# embeddable link to Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink

Is there a way I can embed a link back to Google Chrome on my website? I mean an embeddable image link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to embed the Google Chrome logo on your page and when the user clicks the it they get redirected to the Google Chrome home page? Try this:

`<a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/landing_chrome_mac.html?hl=en">
<img src="https://www.google.com/intl/en/images/logos/chrome_logo.gif" alt="Google Chrome" />
</a>`

[image: Google Chrome]

Comment: You should probably change the link to one that isn't Mac specific.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks! @thirtydot yes, just abreviate the url to `http://www.google.com/chrome`